# Building adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, adjacency-matrix

I have a origin & destination airport and the number of flights between two airports on a certain year.

```
       ORIGIN_AIRPORT DESTINATION_AIRPORT  Counts
0               ABE                 ATL     170
1               ABE                 DTW     154
2               ABE                 ORD      69
3               ABI                 DFW     530
4               ABQ                 ATL     123
...             ...                 ...     ...
4293            XNA                 MSP      63
4294            XNA                 ORD     490
4295            YAK                 CDV      67
4296            YAK                 JNU      67
4297            YUM                 PHX     377
```

Is there a way to form an adjacency matrix in python using this data? There should be a 0 if there is no connection (no flights) between airports and 1 if there is a connection.

The matrix should be N x N. It should look something like this:

```
Adjacency Matrix:
        ABE ABI ABQ ATL DTW ORD DFW
ABE     0   0   0   1   1   1   0
ABI     0   0   0   0   0   0   1
ABQ     0   0   0   1   0   0   0
ATL     1   0   1   0   0   0   0
DTW     1   0   0   0   0   0   0
ORD     1   0   0   0   0   0   0
DFW     0   1   0   0   0   0   0

...
```

Comment: Yes, just go trough the data and edit a matrix on the fly. Where is the problem ? You could even use a sparse matrix format to avoid storing zeros

Comment: There are 4297 rows and 315 distinct airports, I cannot go through the data manually and plus I need an N x N matrix

Comment: I guess that's what code is for, use a loop it'll go through the 4294 rows in milliseconds. Of course, you can probably find a built in solution that does the trick but it's not always the case and built-in solution should be use as a faster way to do something you can do, not to do something you can not do. Otherwise, you'll fast have trouble debugging your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.crosstab()`:

```py
pd.crosstab(df["ORIGIN_AIRPORT"], df["DESTINATION_AIRPORT"])
```

This outputs:

```py
DESTINATION_AIRPORT  ATL  DFW  DTW  ORD
ORIGIN_AIRPORT
ABE                    1    0    1    1
ABI                    0    1    0    0
ABQ                    1    0    0    0
```